# How to rotate the thumbnail image in a picture library in SP2013

Tags: list-view, picture, thumbnail

I have an email enabled picture library in SharePoint 2013 (on prem) that detaches the images from emails. This works great but some of the pictures are tilted 90 degrees in the thumbnails view. As far as I can tell none of the options in the ribbon allows me to rotate the thumbnail, and I guess this must be a pretty common complaint, and that a solution exists?

Comment: No OOTB solution as far as I know, normally you rotate on the client or in the code uploading the image before adding it to SP